# wxpython EVT_KEY_DOWN not binding to the Frame

Tags: python, wxpython

**Disclaimer:**  Perhaps I've gone about this incorrectly, but Im only about 24 hours into GUI development with wxpython.  So general advice is appreciated.

**Goal:**  I'm trying to familiarize myself with wxpython by making a simple screen saver.

**Problem:**  Im trying to bind both mouse movement, and keyboard movement (aka trying to capture ANY user input) so it Destroys() the app on event (typical screensaver behavior).  So far, my mouse events are being captured and it destroys properly, but my keyboard events are not (pound on my keyboard as I might!).  I've tried EVT_CHAR and CHAR_HOOK as other SO posts have recommended.  I've even go as far to see where my focus is - as I think that this is my problem (notice the line has self.SetFocus() - if you remove this, and move the mouse, the returned "self.FindFocus()" thats triggered by mouse movement events is returning None... with the SetFocus() it is now returning my class of SpaceFrame).

**Question:**  Why can't I capture key strokes and activate my keyboardMovement() method?  Interestingly enough, the example from [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/) works just fine for the keyboard events down/up.  So I'm 100% it's user error.

```
import wx
import random

MAX_INVADERS = 10
INVADERS_COLORS = ["yellow_invader",
                   "green_invader",
                   "blue_invader",
                   "red_invader"]


class SpaceFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        The generic subclassed Frame/"space" window.  All of the invaders fall
        into this frame.  All animation happens here as the parent window
        as well.
        """
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Space Invaders", pos=(0, 0))
        self.SetFocus()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.mouseMovement)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.keyboardMovement)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('black')
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black')
        self.monitorSize = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        for invader in range(0, MAX_INVADERS, 1):
            randX = random.randint(0, self.monitorSize[0])
            self.showInvader(coords=(randX, 0),
                             invader=random.choice(INVADERS_COLORS),
                             scale=(random.randint(2, 10)/100.0))

    def mouseMovement(self, event, *args):
        print self.FindFocus()

    def keyboardMovement(self, event, *args):
        self.Destroy()

    def showInvader(self, coords=(0, 0), invader="green_invader", scale=.05):
        """
        Displays an invader on the screen
        """
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.dropInvader, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.invader = wx.Bitmap("{0}.png".format(invader))
        self.invader = wx.ImageFromBitmap(self.invader)
        self.invader = self.invader.Scale((self.invader.GetWidth()*scale),
                                          (self.invader.GetHeight()*scale),
                                          wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        self.result = wx.BitmapFromImage(self.invader)
        self.control = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.result)
        self.control.SetPosition(coords)
        self.panel.Show(True)

    def moveInvader(self, coords):
        self.control.SetPosition(coords)

    def dropInvader(self, *args):
        # print "this hit"
        self.control.SetPosition((100, 600))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = wx.PySimpleApp()
    window = SpaceFrame()
    window.ShowFullScreen(True, style=wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL)
    application.MainLoop()
```

**Research Done So Far:**  Maybe I missed something, but nothing stood out to me here.

- [Source1](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/) - Mouse Vs Python examples
- [Source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570254/in-wxpython-how-do-you-bind-a-evt-key-down-event-to-the-whole-window) - SO similar problem (but not exactly my solution)
- [Source3](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.KeyEvent-class.html) - WXpython forum/mailing list
- [Source4](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/question-how-to-catch-the-keyboard-event-in-wxpython-td2370983.html) - WXpython forum/mailing list

Comment: The keyboard events work if I comment out the self.invader and self.control portions of code in the showInvader function. Unfortunately, that also seems to disable the mouse movement destruction capabilities.

Comment: Hmmm... that's interesting, I wouldn't have guessed that would have happened.  Any thoughts how I might go about debugging this?  I'm still spinning my wheels that this is caused by a focus issue (but then again, maybe not).  Really, my first hunch was because I am in a VM linux environment, I thought maybe the VM could have been throwing things off, but your examples from your blog work just fine...  /totally confused/.  Love your blog btw!  Been using it for a few years now.  *high five*

Comment: Yeah, it is odd. I'm not sure the wx.Frame is maintaining the focus. Maybe the wx.Bitmap is somehow stealing the focus and causing the problem. I know that the wx.Panel doesn't accept focus very well as it will try to pass the focus on to its children. I wonder if the frame is doing something similar. You might ask over on the wxPython mailing list. Oh and thanks for the kind words. I'm glad the blog has been helpful.