# wxpython don't capture EVT_HELP

Tags: python, events, wxpython, keyboard-events

I have a little problem, I am using FreeBSD but this problem occurs on linux as well.

I try to send an wx.EVT_HELP by the use of the key F1, but nothing happens:

```
import logging as log
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_HELP, self.function)
        self.SetFocus()
        self.Show(True)

    def function(self, event=None):
        print "drin"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    gui = MainWindow(None, "test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

I tried it with a panel like in [wxpython can't capture EVT_KEY_DOWN enent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294147/wxpython-cant-capture-evt-key-down-enent)

```
import logging as log
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_HELP, self.function)
        self.panel.SetFocus()
        self.Show(True)

    def function(self, event=None):
        print "drin"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    gui = MainWindow(None, "test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

but this didn't work either (and I would want to prevent panels in my case). The only possibilities I know is to use wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN with panels or wx.CHAR_HOOK (works without panels) but in both cases they bind every keyevent to my function and I want just F1 or rather the wx.EVT_HELP.

Do someone know how I can connect F1 with wx.EVT_HELP, so that my first code would work?

Thanks for your time!

---

Thanks for your help! The AcceleratorTable is something I was looking for! But I don't get why there is a need for a panel, my testcode

```
import logging as log
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        f1_id = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.function, id = f1_id)
        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, wx.WXK_F1, f1_id)])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
        self.SetFocus()
        self.Show(True)

    def function(self, event=None):
        print "drin"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    gui = MainWindow(None, "test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

works but it isn't even using the panel. Is there a possibility to work around a panel? Or is a frame (with unix) not sensitive enough to receive the keyevents? (When I delete the panel in my testcode it works with no key.)

Comment: Have you done any work with [accelerator tables](https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.AcceleratorTable-class.html) as a method of binding keys to events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `wx.AcceleratorTable`. Here's a simple example:

```
import logging as log
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_HELP, self.function)

        f1_id = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.function, id=f1_id)
        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, wx.WXK_F1, f1_id )])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

        self.Show(True)

    def function(self, event=None):
        print "drin"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    gui = MainWindow(None, "test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

This worked for me with wxPython 3.0.2. Classic on Xubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.12

For more information on the topic:

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/
- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.AcceleratorTable.html
- https://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.KeyEvent-class.html

Comment: Hello Mike Driscoll, thanks again for your help. The AcceleratorTable works for me but I have a question about the panel, I wrote it in my frist question.

Comment: I'm not sure why the panel would be required (and it may not be depending on the OS), but you almost always want one inside of a `wx.Frame`. The reason is that the panel will give the frame the right look and feel across platforms and also enables tabbing between widgets, if I recall correctly.

Comment: EVT_HELP events are usually not automatically bound to F1. You need to help it out a bit, like what Mike showed with an accelerator table, or handle it by other means. However if you have a wx.ContextHelpButton, or use the wx.ContextHelp class yourself, then you will get EVT_HELP events. See the docs and demo for more details.